# Using a wider inner tube

Tags: tire, innertube

I am switching from 700cx40 to 700cx32. I have a bunch of inner tubes that I bought for the old tires and are in the 40mm range, but I don't know anymore what the range is for each (I didn't keep the packages). Is there a way to tell? Or, if no, what can happen if I use a wider tube (say, a 35-xx or 37-xx tube on a 32mm tire)?

EDIT: OK, I see, the dimension is written on the tube. So, I have a 700 x35/43 tube. Is it safe to use it on 32?

Comment: Normally the size range of the tube is printed on the side of it.

Comment: It can fold on you .   Give it light pump and put it in the tire to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly safe to use the next larger size tube in a smaller tire. It's a common trick used by bike messengers to reduce the chance of flats. The only downside is a slightly heavier wheel since you're using more tube that you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Probably fine - if you're really worried, buy new inner tubes and carry one of those bigger ones as your spare.  Remember you're talking about 3 mm in size, in something made of rubber that

Even if its not race-perfect, will be good enough to get you home, or give away to a fellow cyclist.

Could also run them on a stationary trainer if you use one.